# Can somebody explain me how it works? FilledStacks.com

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have problem to understand why the code is written in this way. How it works exactly?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

abstract class BaseModelWidget<T> extends Widget {
  @protected
  Widget build(BuildContext context, T model);

  @override
  _DataProviderElement<T> createElement() => _DataProviderElement<T>(this);
}

class _DataProviderElement<T> extends ComponentElement {
  _DataProviderElement(BaseModelWidget widget) : super(widget);

  @override
  BaseModelWidget get widget => super.widget;

  @override
  Widget build() => widget.build(this, Provider.of<T>(this));
}
```

Comment: Hi! You can help others by narrowing your question. What about the code do you understand and do you not understand? The [generics](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics), the [abstract class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes), the [`Provider` call](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or something else? If you understand the parts, you should be able to understand the whole.